# Can a class be static in php

Tags: php, class, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to create static classes in PHP (like in C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468642/is-it-possible-to-create-static-classes-in-php-like-in-c)

Can any one tell me if a php class can be declared as static ?

```
static class StaticClass
{
    public static function staticMethod()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

This code giving me error.parse error: parse error, expecting `T_VARIABLE'

Comment: Not an **exact** duplicate unless OP does want to strongly mimic C# static classes.

Comment: @BoltClock: but group [Can be done AND mimic C#] is just a subset of [Can be done], so that questions answers this one and goes more into it.

Comment: Not yet, ***may*** be possible in the future, since it was already suggested a few times -  https://wiki.php.net/rfc/static-classes however I'm not sure what to think about "Status: in the works" and "Date: 2008-05-03" x)

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't explicitly declare a PHP class as static.

You can make its constructor private so attempting to instantiate it (at least from outside the class) causes fatal errors.

```
class StaticClass
{
    private function __construct() {}

    public static function staticMethod()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}

// Fatal error: Call to private StaticClass::__construct() from invalid context
new StaticClass();
```

If you're looking to implement static initialization and other features found in C# static classes, see the other linked question. Otherwise if all you want is to group some utility methods into a class, simply privatizing the constructor should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for you support,In this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468642/is-it-possible-to-create-static-classes-in-php-like-in-c

Answer 5 saying :You can have static classes in PHP.Is it true.I just want to know only this .Plz...

Comment: @Neelesh: You can write a class and treat it as if it were a static class, but you cannot write `static class` in PHP.

Comment: @Neelesh: Be sure to accept an answer by clicking the tick mark at the left.

Answer (score 3):

One other alternative is to create the class as `abstract`.  While it still can be extended and instantiated, it can't directly be.

```
abstract class test {
    public static function foo() {
    }
}

$foo = new test(); // Fatal error, can't instantiate abstract class
```

If you go with a private constructor, I'd suggest also making it `final`, since otherwise an extending class can override it and actually instantiate the class (as long as it doesn't call `parent::__construct()`:

```
class test {
    private final function __construct() {}
}
class test2 extends test {
    public function __construct() {} // fatal error, can't extend final method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable as static, and a method, but not a class:

```
static public $stat_sample = 'test';

static public getSample() {
 return "test";
}
```