# Would a method in a static class and a static class method have the same callabilty?

Tags: php, class, static, static-methods

I guess my question is would

```
static class example1{
    function example1_function(){};     
}
```

and

```
class example2{
    static function example2_function(){};
}
```

lead to the same result, which is both `example1->example1_function()` and `example2->example2_function()` have the same callabilty. Would both be defined as static and usable as such?

Comment: The `static class` and the `class class` will lead to parse errors.

Comment: Take a look on this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468642/is-it-possible-to-create-static-classes-in-php-like-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot declare a class as a static class, as stated by other members here, but there is a method where you can stop the class from becoming an object, you can use the `abstract` keyword to specify the object should not be instantiated using the new keyword, this is good for inheritance etc.

```
abstract class Something
{
}
```

Doing `new Something` would trigger an error stating you cannot instantiate the class, you can then declare your static methods like so:

```
abstract class Something
{
    public static function Else()
    {
    }
}
```

You still have to declare you methods as `static`, this is just the way it is.

and then you can use like so:

```
Something::Else();
```

Hope this clears up a few thing's

Comment: As opposed to `function Else()`? (not in a class)

Comment: Please explain your comment, it can't understand what your referring to ?

Comment: Why would you create a class of all static methods as opposed to just writing functions for the methods?

Comment: Because it act's as a wrapper, does not effect global scope, allows you to use a form of OOP `self::OtherMethod()`

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not allow you to declare a class static.

To call a static method, you must use the `::` operator.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned in the comments, the static keyword is not used for classes in that way (syntax).

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php