# is there any significance of using ::(scope resolution operator) with an object to access class variables?

Tags: php, class

Although it is **allowed** to access class variables using the syntax:- ***$object::$variable***, does it hold any significance i.e. in case of accessing class variables we can use either the **classname or an object** of that class to access a class variable isn't it?

Comment: FYI this operator is called `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM` as [seen in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php), not a "scope resolution operator", since it has little to do with scope in PHP.

Comment: @War10ck "Static classes" do not exist in PHP ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468642/is-it-possible-to-create-static-classes-in-php-like-in-c)).

Comment: ooh, apparently it *is* called a "scope resolution operator" after all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operator is used to access **static** variables. This means that the variable is linked to the class, and not to an instance of that class. i.e. shared over all instances.

here's an example to show you what I mean:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static $myStaticVar;
    public $myObjectVar;
}

$instance1 = new MyClass();
$instance2 = new MyClass();

// normal vars are linked to an instance of a class
$instance1->myObjectVar = 'value1';
$instance2->myObjectVar = 'value2';

// statics are shared between all instances of the same class
$instance1::$myStaticVar = 'value3';

echo $instance2::$myStaticVar; // results in 'value3'!
```

Comment: This one is a practical approach to answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this?

```
<?php

class A {
    public static $b = 'Hello World!';
}

echo A::$b;
$obj = new A();
echo $obj::$b;
```

***Warning:** I do **not** recommend to access a static class member using an instance variable.*

This only works for PHP >= 5.3.0.

PHP <= 5.2.17 doesn't like `$obj::$b` and throws a syntax error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM,
>   expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Bubba downvoted all other answers to make his come up on top, I checked his profile to confirm this.

Comment: @NDM Thanks for informing me. Have you already reported him? (I can't see his downvotes at his profile, can you give me a link, please?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/660636/bubba?tab=reputation the -2 on this question marks 2 downvotes, yours and my answer... I've just downvoted him aswell, dont think flagging will help...

Comment: @NDM Please revert your downvote ('revenge' doesn't help). Flagging defintely helps, the SO moderator team is very kind.